# Option on Futures - Black Equation Derivation

Tags: black-scholes

How to derive Generalised Black equation for Option on Future using generalised Black Scholes Equation

$$F=exp(r(T−t))S$$

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2F^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial F^2}  -rV = 0$$

From
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} -rV = 0$$

Comment: Posting pictures of questions is discouraged here - it is extremely search unfriendly. Please type out the question and formulae.

Comment: This question is also answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377255/black-76-pde-hedging-argument-wrong).

Comment: I din't know how to, hence attached pictures, any way I can add Differential Equations on Stack?

Comment: You can use latex. I have a pending edit that will put it in for the second formula, you can replace the image.

Comment: ok, used your code and made edits, thanks Will for your help. I hope my maths is right.

Comment: Don't understand why is it down voted, this is so discouraging. This is part of learning process... everyone happens to be a beginner once!

Comment: it was down voted because the question was not written well, that is what happens here. In the end you fixed it though. You should have *answered* your question with am answer though, not by changing the question. Also, I you need subscripts on the ts.

Comment: I did later, when I learnt how to. Was desperate to find a solution ha ha. Edited, and answered my question below. "Also, I you need subscripts on the ts" don't understand this part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62680/discussion-between-vinay-dwivedi-and-will).

Answer (score 1):

Update:Will's link helped [Derivation](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35227/option-on-futures-black-equation-derivation): I applied following Chain rule
V=(**F**,t) and F = (**S**, t) (F = **Forward Price**, S = **Underlying Price**)

I get

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial F}\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}  + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial t} $$

=  $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial F}\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}  + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$$

gets me
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} - rF\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$$

Substituting in Black Scholes equation, RS term gets cancelled out w.r.t F.

Future price has No value at the time of Purchase!

Thanks a lot!